# Is there a way to check whether a stackful coroutine is in the context of a given strand?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Given a [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/yield_context.html) object `y`, and a strand `s`, is there a way to check whether `y` represents a coroutine in the context of `s` or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `yield_context` and `strand` object, it is not possible to detect if a `yield_context`'s executor context is a specific `strand`.  However, within the execution of a coroutine, one can detect if the current coroutine's executor context is a specific `strand` via invoking [`strand::running_in_this_thread()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/running_in_this_thread.html).  It is a subtle distinction, but here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dea663fb69f530ed) its usage:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand1(io_service);
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand2(io_service);
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand3(strand1);

  boost::asio::spawn(strand1,
    [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
      assert(strand1.running_in_this_thread());
      assert(!strand2.running_in_this_thread());
      assert(strand3.running_in_this_thread());

      // Access implementation details.
      auto strand4 = yield.handler_.dispatcher_;
      assert(strand4.running_in_this_thread());

      // No way to compare strands to one another.  Although strand1, strand3,
      // and strand4 use the same strand implementation, the strand objects
      // are neither identifiable nor comparable.
    });

  io_service.run();
}
```

The reason one cannot detect if a `yield_context` object's executor context is a specific `strand` object is because the [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) API provides neither a way to perform identification nor comparison.  In the above example, although `strand1`, `strand3`, and `strand4` refer to the same strand implementation, the only way to deduce that they use the same implementation is to check each one within the execution context of one of the strands.  Furthermore, even if strands were comparable, the supported API for [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/yield_context.html) does not expose the coroutine's executor context.